# Issue w/ pandas.index.get_loc() when match is found, TypeError: ("'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 1')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Below is the example to reproduce the error:

```
testx1df = pd.DataFrame()
testx1df['A'] = [100,200,300,400]
testx1df['B'] = [15,60,35,11]
testx1df['C'] = [11,45,22,9]
testx1df['D'] = [5,15,11,3]
testx1df['E'] = [1,6,4,0]


(testx1df[testx1df < 6].apply(lambda x: x.index.get_loc(x.first_valid_index(), method='ffill'), axis=1))
```

The desired output should be a list or array with the values [3,NaN,4,3]. The NaN because it does not satisfy the criteria.

I checked the pandas references and it says that for cases when you do not have an exact match you can change the "method" to 'fill', 'brill', or 'nearest' to pick the previous, next, or closest index. Based on this, if i indicated the method as 'ffill' it would give me an index of 4 instead of NaN. However, when i do so it does not work and i get the error show in the question title. For criteria higher than 6 it works fine but it doesn't for less than 6 due to the fact that the second row in the data frame does not satisfy it.

Is there a way around this issue? should it not work for my example(return previous index of 3 or 4)?

One solution i thought of is to add a dummy column populated by zeros so that is has a place to "find" and index that satisfies the criteria but this is a bit crude to me and i think there is a more efficient solution out there.

Comment: can you post the desired output required?

Comment: @prahasanam_boi i just added the desired outcome to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this:

```
import numpy as np
ls = list(testx1df[testx1df<6].T.isna().sum())
ls = [np.nan if x==testx1df.shape[1] else x for x in ls]
print(ls)
```

Comment: this worked well for me. If possible could you explain your code so i understand how it is solving the problem that pandas.index.get_loc struggled to address

Comment: I missed the above comment. `testx1df[testx1df<6]` gives a dataframe with elements satisfying the condition, rest filled with 'NaN'. Transposing and calculating the column-wise count of 'NaN' values gives the row-wise count that fails the condition, what's required. Now if all row fails the condition, it is labelled as 'NaN', in the 3rd line. This is what worked for me, hence I didn't worked on 'get_loc'. Please mark the answer If this is useful.